# blackberry sample application executes in simulator but when I try to load in playbook device there is no response or no error

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

blackberry sample application executes in simulator but when I try to load in device there is no response or no error. I am using a playbook. Also I tried various options in which one of it says to use Desktop manager, I see a different behavior in it too, until I connect playbook to my PC, applications menu is shown in the left of desktop manager, but as soon as the playbook is connected the applications icon disappear. Then I tried to copy paste the .alx / .cod file to downloads folder of playbook, I removed the connection from PC and searched using file manager in device the copied files are not shown, but they are seen when it is connected using device manager. Kindly help me in executing the app within playbook. I am newbie to develop bb application. My target is to develop phone gap app. My playbook OS is 2.0, I am using BBEclipse plugin, webworks too.

Another update regarding phonegap application, I followed the steps from wiki phonegap documentation and finally when I tried to package the application (After getting all keys, registering to server etc). This is the error response seen. Kindly help to fix this.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\SMI 123 U\My Documents\Research In Motion\BlackBerry W
ebWorks SDK for TabletOS 2.2.0.5\bbwp>bbwp "C:\Documents and Settings\SMI 123 U\
Desktop\sample\sample.zip" -o "C:\Documents and Settings\SMI 123 U\Desktop"
[INFO]                  Parsing command line options
[INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
[INFO]                  Validating WebWorks archive
[INFO]                  Parsing config.xml
[INFO]                  Populating application source
[INFO]                  Compiling WebWorks application
[INFO]                  Packaging the bar file
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at net.rim.tumbler.airpackager.AirPackager.createSplashscreen(AirPackage
r.java:726)
        at net.rim.tumbler.airpackager.AirPackager.run(AirPackager.java:191)
        at net.rim.tumbler.WidgetPackager.go(WidgetPackager.java:152)
        at net.rim.tumbler.WidgetPackager.main(WidgetPackager.java:77)
[ERROR]                 Air Packager exception occurred
```

I tried using another command also

```
C:\Documents and Settings\SMI 123 U\My Documents\Research In Motion\BlackBerry W
ebWorks SDK for TabletOS 2.2.0.5\bbwp>bbwp "C:\Documents and Settings\SMI 123 U\
Desktop\sample\sample.zip" -g 12345678 -buildId 1 -o "C:\Documents and Settings\
SMI 123 U\Desktop"
[INFO]                  Parsing command line options
[INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
[INFO]                  Validating WebWorks archive
[INFO]                  Parsing config.xml
[INFO]                  Populating application source
[INFO]                  Compiling WebWorks application
[INFO]                  Packaging the bar file
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at net.rim.tumbler.airpackager.AirPackager.createSplashscreen(AirPackage
r.java:726)
        at net.rim.tumbler.airpackager.AirPackager.run(AirPackager.java:191)
        at net.rim.tumbler.WidgetPackager.go(WidgetPackager.java:152)
        at net.rim.tumbler.WidgetPackager.main(WidgetPackager.java:77)
[ERROR]                 Air Packager exception occurred
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The developer support forum thread "[New Webworks SDK Error While Packaging Application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/New-Webworks-SDK-Error-While-Packaging-Application/td-p/1027213)" has an answer for you.